# error:Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, android, adb

I am getting this error all the time when i am starting to run the code then its showing attempt to connection and again its one line code coming between 5 or 6 attempt saying Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Here all I have did to make run correctly:

- update all thing in android studio
- kill abd-server and start-server
  -create path  for plate form tool

Is this happening because of i have also install eclipse and xampp on my laptop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932369/adb-connection-erroran-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-ho)

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to get this error answer but i didn't get answer , and i check to all place even at this place ,solution is if you have downloaded any other oracle or any other database software if you have downloaded oracle database so uninstall it and you adb connection will work again